# What version of iTunes runs on Windows 7 and where is it available?

Tags: windows-7, itunes

What version of iTunes runs on Windows 7 and where is it available?

I looked at https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT210384 and it only mentions for Windows 10 and Windows 8.

Comment: tested w10 one didn't work...said requirese win10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[iTunes 12.10.11 for Windows (Windows 64 bit)](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2065?locale=en_US) should work wuth Windows 7.
According to the same [page](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2065?locale=en_US):

> This update allows you to sync your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch on Windows 7 and Windows 8 PCs.

Answer (score 2):

#### What version of iTunes runs on Windows 7 and where is it available?

I'm running 12.10.11.2 on Windows 7.

You can download iTunes 12.10.11 for Windows (Windows 64 bit) from [iTunes 12.10.11 for Windows (Windows 64 bit)](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2065?locale=en_US):

> System Requirements
>
> Hardware:
>
> - PC with a 1GHz Intel or AMD processor with support for SSE2 and 512MB of RAM
> - To play standard-definition video from the iTunes Store, an Intel Pentium D or faster processor, 512MB of RAM, and a DirectX
>   9.0–compatible video card is required
> - To play 720p HD video, an iTunes LP, or iTunes Extras, a 2.0GHz Intel Core 2 Duo or faster processor, 1GB of RAM, and an Intel GMA
>   X3000, ATI Radeon X1300, or NVIDIA GeForce 6150 or better is required
> - To play 1080p HD video, a 2.4GHz Intel Core 2 Duo or faster processor, 2GB of RAM, and an Intel GMA X4500HD, ATI Radeon HD 2400,
>   or NVIDIA GeForce 8300 GS or better is required
> - Screen resolution of 1024x768 or greater; 1280x800 or greater is required to play an iTunes LP or iTunes Extras
> - 16-bit sound card and speakers Internet connection to use Apple Music, the iTunes Store, and iTunes Extras
> - iTunes-compatible CD or DVD recorder to create audio CDs, MP3 CDs, or backup CDs or DVDs. Songs from the Apple Music catalog cannot be
>   burned to a CD.
>
> Software:
>
> - Windows 7 or later
> - 64-bit editions of Windows require the iTunes 64-bit installer
> - 400MB of available disk space
> - Some third-party visualizers may no longer be compatible with this version of iTunes. Please contact the developer for an updated
>   visualizer that is compatible with iTunes 12.1 or later. Apple Music,
>   iTunes Store, and iTunes Match availability may vary by country Apple
>   Music trial requires sign-up and is available for new subscribers
>   only. Plan automatically renews after trial.

Answer (score 2):

See the TechSpot article
[Apple iTunes 12.12.2.2 for Windows XP, 7, 8, 10 and 11](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/70-apple-itunes-for-windows.html).

It contains links to downloads for all the versions of Windows:
Windows 11/10 64-bit, Windows 11/10 32-bit, Windows 7/8 64-bit,
Windows 7/8 32-bit, and Windows XP.

Note that not all the downloads are for the same version.
For example, the Windows 11/10 version is 12.12.2.2,
but for Windows 7 is 12.10.10, and for Windows XP still
another version.

Comment: thanks, i've seen this before where a windows 8 download works on win7 but a win10 one doesn't.. any idea why that is?

Comment: @barlop Have you are installed the Windows update that makes Windows 7 support SHA256 hashes in code signing certificates. Not sure if it is automatically installed via Windows update. If it misses that could be a reason.

Comment: @Robert Reason for what? The windows 10 one works for windows 10 not earlier. The windows 8 one works for windows 8 and windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

The one for windows 8 seems to work.

The one for windows 10 won't work, and says it requires windows 10.

The one for windows 8, so, i.e. one that works on windows 7, says it's version 12.10.11.2  https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT210384

there is also a website called techspot that says it has an itunes download for windows 7 tested in virustotal.  https://www.techspot.com/downloads/70-apple-itunes-for-windows.html#download_scroll  Note- apparently the title on the techspot article is misleading re version, eg see harry's post about versions of itunes and version of windows.